# How to merge reads effectively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastq

Okay, so for a project i have about 4000 reads (Minion in a fastq file), some of these reads overlap, and i would like to merge these as to make a contig later on. (going to do a genome assembly in the end)

```
Read 1: forward
ATGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTAAGGTTAACACAAAGACACCGACAACTTTCTTCA
Read 2: forward
AGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTAAGGTTAACACAAAAGACACCGACAACTTTCTTATCGA
Read 3: forward
ACTGTACTAAGTTCAGTTACTTATGCCTAAGGTTAACACCGAAGACACCTAATACTTTCTTATG
Read 4: forward
AGTGTACTTCGTCCTATTACCAATTGCTTAGGCGAACACAAGCGACACCGATAACTTTCTTTAGCA
Read 5: reverse
AGTGTACCCCGTTCATATTACGTATTGCTAAGGCAAACACAAAAGAGCCCGACAACTTTCTTA
```

How do i merge these reads? The simpelst solution in my head would be to just take read one, what ever is the same or longer then the read in read 2 append and keep doing that, but that does not feel right, how do i know where to start merging?

The output i need would look something like this:

```
---r1--->
  ----r2--->
     ---r3---->
       --r4-->
    <---r5--
_____contig____
```

Can anybody tell me how i achieve this without losing information from the reads? Most reads i have, have more then one overlapping read that is in the file, the first one has atleast 10 forward overlapping structures with other reads and three reverse.

A way to combine the reads in order to make them into contigs, i would like to understand how i can best tackle this issue.

Comment: There are quite a few papers trying to solve this subject.  Why don't you use some of the existing tools for this duty?

Comment: This is called "assembly" and, if you don't have a reference genome to work against, "de novo assembly." As @Poshi implies there are many existing tools for this task, so it doesn't make sense to be writing your own code (unless it's some type of learning exercise).